# C++: Building extensions with cmake for Boost.Python gives "undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6python5numpy10initializeEb"

Tags: python, numpy, boost, cmake

I am trying to make a basic 'hello world' Python.Boost example library using `cmake`.
Versions of packages:

- cmake: 3.22.1
- Boost: 1.81.0
- Python: Python 3.10.8 (from anaconda)
- g++: 11.3.0 (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)

When I load the compiled Python the library it gives me an error `undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6python5numpy10initializeEb`.

Here are the files: **CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(hello_ext)

# Find python and Boost - both are required dependencies
find_package(PythonLibs 3.10 REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)

# Without this, any build libraries automatically have names "lib{x}.so"
set(CMAKE_SHARED_MODULE_PREFIX "")

# Add a shared module - modules are intended to be imported at runtime.
# - This is where you add the source files
add_library(hello_ext MODULE hello_ext.cpp)

# Set up the libraries and header search paths for this target
target_link_libraries(hello_ext ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(hello_ext PRIVATE ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

**hello_ext.cpp**

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>

namespace py = boost::python;
namespace np = boost::python::numpy;

char const* greet()
{
  return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
  Py_Initialize();
  np::initialize();

  using namespace boost::python;
  def("greet", greet);
}
```

Then I run cmake and make:

```
mkdir _build
cd _build
cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.10.so (found suitable version "3.10.6", minimum required is "3.10") 
-- Found Boost: /usr/lib/cmake/Boost-1.81.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.81.0") found components: python 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/git/hello_ext/_build
```

Compilation works fine

```
(py310) ➜  ~/git/hello_ext/_build make
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/hello_ext.dir/hello_ext.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared module hello_ext.so
[100%] Built target hello_ext
```

However, when I load the extension I get an `undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6python5numpy10initializeEb` error:

```
In [1]: import hello_ext
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import hello_ext

ImportError: /home/user/git/hello_ext/_build/hello_ext.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6python5numpy10initializeEb
```

The loading not to give the undefined symbol error.

Comment: My bad, needed to also include numpy in the CMake find_package:
`find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python numpy REQUIRED)`

Comment: Yo, I'm havaving similar issues, have you had this ? ```  Could NOT find Boost (missing: python numpy) (found suitable version   "1.81.0", minimum required is "1.81.0")```
Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Did not have this error. But this looks like your boost is not a full version. I followed the guide to install full boost version.